# Bits Access Condition per Mifare Classic

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I'm working with a tag Mifare Classic 1k. 
I was able to read most of the data, but now I want to understand the bits for access conditions in the third block of each sector. I have read the official documentation on this web site: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S50YYX.pdf, but I could not understand how to interpret the bits in relation with keys a and B. Can someone help me understand it?

Comment: I know that you asked a long time ago. Could you be more specific about what bits you are talking about? Is you question about how C1, C2 and C3 have influence over keyA and keyB behavior or would you like to understand what means the 6-byte sequence reserved for keyA and keyB in the trailer block?

Answer (score 2):

There is a (very) old MIFARE reader program by NXP, called "MifareWnd" available at http://www.nxp.com/documents/software/PE089917.zip.
It can also be used to encode and decode the access control bits.

Instructions: Download it, install it and start it. In the text entry field with the label "Block" enter the address of a sector trailer (e.g. "3"), this enables the button "Edit AC". If you want to decode settings, enter the contents of the sector trailer in hexadecimal in the text field with the label "HEX". Click "Edit AC" to see the decoded contents. You can also edit the settings and get the encoded values.

Comment: this link is unavailable, could you please upload this software in new link?